# Problems with using of dependent pairs in Agda

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I'm learning [Agda by tutorial](http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Index.html), and now I'm reading about dependent pairs.

So, this is the fragment of code:

```
data Σ (A : Set) (B : A → Set) : Set where
  _,_ : (a : A) → (b : B a) → Σ A B

infixr 4 _,_

Σprojₗ : {A : Set}{B : A → Set} → Σ A B → A
Σprojₗ (a , b) = a

data _∈_ {A : Set}(x : A) : List A → Set where
  first : {xs : List A} → x ∈ x ∷ xs
  later : {y : A}{xs : List A} → x ∈ xs → x ∈ y ∷ xs

infix 4 _∈_

_!_ : ∀{A : Set} → List A → ℕ → Maybe A
  [] ! _           = nothing
  x ∷ xs ! zero    = just x
  x ∷ xs ! (suc n) = xs ! n

infix 5 _!_

lookup : ∀ {A}{x : A}(xs : List A) → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≡ just x)
```

`_,_` is a constructor of dependent pair, `Σprojₗ` returns first part of pair, `_∈_` is a relation of membership, `lst ! i` returns `just $(i-th element)` if `list`'s length is greater or equal than i, `nothing` — otherwise. I want to write a `lookup` function which takes list `xs`, proof of membership `x ∈ xs`, and returns dependent pair of natural number and function which for natural number `n` returns proof (or disproof) of the fact that n-th element of list is `just x`. Now the function looks like

```
lookup : ∀ {A}{x : A}(xs : List A) → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≣ just x)
lookup {A} {x} .(x ∷ xs) (inHead {xs}) = 0 , refl
lookup .(y ∷ xs) (inTail {y} {xs} proof) = (1 + Σprojₗ (lookup xs proof)) , ?
```

I suppose that I should write some function like `Σprojᵣ` (it should return second element of pair, function with signature `A → Set`) for filling the hole, but I have no idea how to write it. The only variant which was typechecked is

```
Σprojᵣ : {A : Set}{B : A → Set} → Σ A B → (A → Set)
Σprojᵣ {A} {B} (a , b) = B
```

, but I didn't managed how to finish `lookup` function with this. How do I solve this exercise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, assuming that `Σprojᵣ` projects the second element of the pair, `Σprojᵣ (lookup xs proof)` is correct solution which fits into the hole. The question is, how to write this projection?

---

If we had ordinary non-dependent pairs, writing both projections is easy:

```
data _×_ (A B : Set) : Set where
  _,′_ : A → B → A × B

fst : ∀ {A B} → A × B → A
fst (a ,′ b) = a

snd : ∀ {A B} → A × B → B
snd (a ,′ b) = b
```

What makes it so hard when we use dependent pair? The hint is hidden in the very name: the second component depends on the value of first and we have to somehow capture this in our type.

So, we start with:

```
data Σ (A : Set) (B : A → Set) : Set where
  _,_ : (a : A) → B a → Σ A B
```

Writing the projection for the left component is easy (note that I'm calling it `proj₁` instead of `Σprojₗ`, that's what the standard library does):

```
proj₁ : {A : Set} {B : A → Set} → Σ A B → A
proj₁ (a , b) = a
```

Now, the second projection should look a bit like this:

```
proj₂ : {A : Set} {B : A → Set} → Σ A B → B ?
proj₂ (a , b) = b
```

But `B` *what*? Since the type of the second component depends on the value of the first one, we somehow need to smuggle it through `B`.

We need to be able to refer to our pair, let's do it:

```
proj₂ : {A : Set} {B : A → Set} (pair : Σ A B) → B ?
```

And now, the first component of our pair is `proj₁ pair`, so let's fill that in:

```
proj₂ : {A : Set} {B : A → Set} (pair : Σ A B) → B (proj₁ pair)
```

And indeed, this typechecks!

---

There are, however, easier solutions than writing `proj₂` by hand.

Instead of defining `Σ` as a `data`, we can define it as a `record`. Records are special case of `data` declarations that have only one constructor. The nice thing is that records give you the projections for free:

```
record Σ (A : Set) (B : A → Set) : Set where
  constructor _,_
  field
    proj₁ : A
    proj₂ : B proj₁

open Σ  -- opens the implicit record module
```

This (among other useful things) gives you projections `proj₁` and `proj₂`.

---

We can also deconstruct the pair with `with` statement and avoid this `proj` bussiness altogether:

```
lookup : ∀ {A} {x : A}(xs : List A) → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≡ just x)
lookup {x = x} .(x ∷ xs) (first {xs}) = 0 , refl
lookup         .(y ∷ xs) (later {y} {xs} p) with lookup xs p
... | n , p′ = suc n , p′
```

`with` allows you to pattern match not only on the arguments of the function, but also on intermediate expressions. If you are familiar with Haskell, it's something like a `case`.

---

Now, this is almost ideal solution, but still can be made a bit better. Notice that we have to bring the implicit `{x}`, `{xs}` and `{y}` into scope just so we can write down the dot pattern. Dot patterns do not participate in pattern matching, they are used as *assertions* that this particular expression is the only one which fits.

For example, in the first equation, the dot pattern tells us that the list must have looked like `x ∷ xs` - we know this because we pattern matched on the proof. Since we only pattern match on the proof, the list argument is a bit redundant:

```
lookup : ∀ {A} {x : A} (xs : List A) → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≡ just x)
lookup ._ first = 0 , refl
lookup ._ (later p) with lookup _ p
... | n , p′ = suc n , p′
```

The compiler can even infer the argument to the recursive call! If the compiler can figure this stuff on its own, we can safely mark it implicit:

```
lookup : ∀ {A} {x : A} {xs : List A} → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≡ just x)
lookup first = 0 , refl
lookup (later p) with lookup p
... | n , p′ = suc n , p′
```

Now, the final step: let's bring in some abstraction. The second equation takes the pair apart, applies some functions (`suc`) and reconstructs the pair - we *map* functions over the pair!

Now, the fully dependent type for `map` is quite complicated. Don't be discouraged if you don't understand! When you come back with more knowledge later, you'll find it fascinating.

```
map : {A C : Set} {B : A → Set} {D : C → Set}
      (f : A → C) (g : ∀ {a} → B a → D (f a)) →
      Σ A B → Σ C D
map f g (a , b) = f a , g b
```

Compare with:

```
map′ : {A B C D : Set}
       (f : A → C) (g : B → D) →
       A × B → C × D
map′ f g (a ,′ b) = f a ,′ g b
```

And we conclude with the very concise:

```
lookup : ∀ {A} {x : A} {xs : List A} → x ∈ xs → Σ ℕ (λ n → xs ! n ≡ just x)
lookup first     = 0 , refl
lookup (later p) = map suc id (lookup p)
```

That is, we map `suc` over the first component and leave the second one unchanged (`id`).

Comment: Thanks for detail answer!
Unfortunately I didn't have time to used to dependent types, so solution with `proj₁ pair` in _signature of function_ was quite unobvious and unexpected.

Comment: @YaroslavSkudarnov: Yup, it's quite strange if you are not used to it. I added some bits about how to make `lookup` look better.